# How can I return the first record of a set of records, grouped by the same values consecutively in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have this set of data:

```
epc     device_id   antenna     created_at
x       a           1           05:00:00    *
x       a           1           05:00:00
x       a           1           05:00:01
x       a           2           05:00:02    *
x       a           1           05:00:03    *
x       b           1           05:00:04    *
x       b           1           05:00:05
x       a           1           05:00:06    *
```

I need to return the first record of epc `x` within each set of the same device and antenna that's inserted consecutively. The tricky part is that it counts as a new set every time either device or antenna changes. Each set could have any number of records in it, as long as they have the same device and antenna and are inserted consecutively. I've highlighted the records to be returned with a `*` here.

I've tried to use `LAG()` with limited success, my problem is that I don't know how to partition with the consecutive limitation.

I'm still fairly new at MySQL so any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a8311)

Answer (score 0):

try filtering out the records with id of "X", then try using distinct

Comment: Distinct doesn't solve my issue. The returned records can be duplicates (same device and antenna), if they are separated by a record with a different device or antenna.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).